# How does one effectively scale node size in gexf for Gephi

Tags: python, gephi

My question is perhaps not so much a coding "how to" question than it is asking for insight into the "internal" workings of Gephi.

I have successfully used the gexf spec to add "viz" tags to a gexf file using Python - specifically, "color" and "size" tags.  However, when opening the file in Gephi, the node size as rendered in Gephi seems anything but linear - or predictable.

For example, in my gexf file, I can set one node size to 3, and another to 2.  When I open the my gexf file in Gephi, the node sized to 3 is readily visible, but the node sized to 2 is barely visible.

I've tried various "remappings" of node size, from linear to natural log to square root in my code that generates the gexf, but nothing seems to make Gephi "behave" in a predictable manner.

Does anyone have any success in using the gexf file format to generate node sizes that Gephi will render in a predictable manner?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've found a reason for my inability to size nodes in Gephi via a properly formatted gexf file:  in the last two versions of Gephi - 0.9.0 and 0.9.1, the Autosize feature of Gephi is "stuck" in the "on" position.  So, until that gets fixed, it does not seem possible to size nodes in advance for visualization in Gephi.